# Probability for the total amount of n random samples

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a normal distribution X~N(μ,$σ^2$), how would I calculate the probability that the total amount of *n* samples of X is above a certain number *k*?
I can think of two ways of going about this:

1. Let  be the distribution of random samples of size
   *n* from the population. Then W~N(μ,$\frac{σ^2}{n}$).
   The probability can be found through P($W>\frac{k}{n}$). Or,
2. If *X~N(μ,$σ^2$)*, then *nX~N(nμ,$(nσ)^2$)*. Thus, the probability could be found through $P(nX>k)$.

It makes sense that the second approach is correct as the question asks for the sum of *n* distributions to be higher than *k*, rather than the first approach which finds the probability that *each* distribution is higher than $\frac{k}{n}$. However, I'm still not sure which is the correct approach.

Comment: Note that you can also start with asking: What is the probability that a given (single) sample has $X>k$ ? That's some fixed probability $p$. Then you repeat this $n$ times ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are wrong.

The sum of $n$ independent random variates $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ follows a normal distribution $N(\sum_i\mu i,\sum_i \sigma_i^2)$ (see for instance [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)).

In your case, it's $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$, and **not** $N(n\mu,n^2\sigma^2)$.

Note that $\sum_i X_i$ does not have the same distribution than $nX_1$.

Comment: Somehow, the first approach gives the same answer. But thanks for the clarification on this!

Comment: @AndrewAnderson I don't know how you found that. The statement that $W\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ is nonsense: $W$ follows a multinormal distribution (it's a sample of size $n$). Or you consider each component of $W$, and each follows $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Same problem with $P(W>k/n)$: what is it supposed to mean if $W$ is a vector? That each component is $>k/n$? But then you have a product of probabilities.